# find sum of prime nos in a given range

Tags: python

I want to write a code which does the following:

1. Given a string it find out the index at which vowels are placed in a given string
2. Multiply each index item by 100
3. Sum all the prime numbers between 1 and the resulting number from last step.

eg: `string='hello'`

in this example:

- The first vowel 'e' is found at index 1 hence 1*100=100
- Sum of prime nos between 1 and 100 is 1060
- Next vowel '0' is found at index 4 hence 4*100=400
- Sum of prime nos between 1 and 400 is 13887

The code is as given for finding index and also multiplying it by 10:

```
string='hello'
vowel='aeiouAEIOU'
res = []
for ele in range(len(string)):
    if string[ele] in 'AEIOUaeiou':
       res.append(ele)
       
       mul_list=[element * 100 for element in res]
```

This generates an output as shown:

[image: Output]

The code for findong prime nos sum is as given:

```
def sum_primes (start,stop):
result=[]
for i in range(start,stop):
    if i==1:
        continue
    prime=True
    for j in range(2,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
        if i%j==0:
            prime=False
            break
    if prime:
        result.append(i)
return sum(result)
```

Now I need a way to update my start and stop variable as per the 3rd condition

Comment: why repost the same question?

Comment: The original question was nor clear so reframed it and posted a new one

Comment: In your case, `start, stop = mul_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this solves you question

```
from math import sqrt

string = "hello"
vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"


# https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-of-all-the-prime-numbers-in-a-given-range/


def checkPrime(numberToCheck):
    if numberToCheck == 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(numberToCheck)) + 1):
        if numberToCheck % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def primeSum(from_no, to):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(to, (from_no - 1), -1):
        # Check for prime
        isPrime = checkPrime(i)
        if isPrime:
            # Sum the prime number
            sum += i
    return sum


for index, element in enumerate(string):
    if element in vowel:
        print(primeSum(1, index * 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the function isPrime of your original question, you can solve the problem using `filter` and `sum`

```
allnums=[x for x in range(mul_list[0],mul_list[1])]
primes=list(filter(lambda x: isPrime(x,2)==True, allnums))

print(sum(primes))
```

Comment: This does not solve actually if you look closely at the question I have to look at each index multiply by 100 and then find sum. Your function gives combined answer

Comment: This solves the challenge posted in the title: find sum of prime numbers in a given range, you just need to get the range in your mul_list.